# Hiding UserForm Without Terminating Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm from which a user has the option to make a selection in an active worksheet which is further used in the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim results As String

    Me.Hide

    results = get_range_from_selection()

    Me.Show

    TextBox.Text = results 

End Sub

Public Function get_range_from_selection() As String

    Dim selection As Range

    Set selection = Application.InputBox("Select rows.", "Select Rows", Type:=8)

    get_range_from_selection = selection.Address

End Function
```

However, on a single screen the UserForm comes in the way of the worksheet making it hard to do the selection and so I need to hide / minimize the form somehow.

I have tried using the UserForm.Hide method, but the problem is that although the UserForm retains textboks values and such, it seems to terminate the button _Click() event subroutine that called the function with above code in the first place. The function executes til the end but the _Click() subroutine which is supposed to do actions in the UserForm based on the selection terminates upon UserForm.Show.

I have tried putting the .Hide/.Show both in the _Click() subroutine and in the called function but the result is the same. Is it supposed to behave like this and is there any workaround or other approach I can try?

Comment: Instead of the Application.Input, use a RefEdit control on the userform?

Comment: See my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you coud try the following code in your userform. I assume the code belongs to a command button which needs to be clicked in order to select the range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rg As Range

    Me.Hide
    Set rg = Application.InputBox("Select rows.", "Select Rows", Type:=8)

    ' Be careful as the user could select a range from a different sheet
    ' or even a different workbook.
    If rg.Parent Is ActiveSheet Then
        rg.Select
    End If

    Me.Show

End Sub
```

You probably used something like `Userform1.Hide` instead of `Me.Hide` which often leads to problems, have a look [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) or [here](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html).

**Update**: You could also "hide" the form like that.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim fHeight As Double
    Dim fWidth As Double

    fHeight = Me.Height
    fWidth = Me.Width
    Me.Height = 0
    Me.Width = 0

    Set rg = Application.InputBox("Select rows.", "Select Rows", Type:=8)

    ' Be careful as the user could select a range from a different sheet
    If rg.Parent Is ActiveSheet Then
        rg.Select
    End If

    Me.Height = fHeight
    Me.Width = fWidth

End Sub
```

In this case code will not be "stopped" by a `Me.Show`.

**Update 2**: Based on the updated post you could try the following code in the userform

```
Option Explicit
Dim fHeight As Double
Dim fWidth As Double

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim results As String

    meHide
    results = get_range_from_selection()
    meShow

    TextBox.Text = results

End Sub
Private Function meHide()
    fHeight = Me.Height
    fWidth = Me.Width
    Me.Height = 0
    Me.Width = 0
End Function
Private Function meShow()
    Me.Height = fHeight
    Me.Width = fWidth
End Function

Public Function get_range_from_selection() As String

    Dim selection As Range

    Set selection = Application.InputBox("Select rows.", "Select Rows", Type:=8)

    get_range_from_selection = selection.Address

End Function
```

Comment: You are correct, the code belongs to a command button, however, the selection code itself is in another function that is called from command button code, I am only returning the range back to the _Click() code. I tried using Me.Hide instead of <Userform name>.Hide, but the result was the same. The _Click() code terminates at Me.Show.

Comment: Then you should edit your post accordingly and add more information and code because my understanding is that the user should select a range and the code should make it to the active selection.

Comment: @norsemanGrey Have you tried `Me.Visible = True` instead? Or better yet, the RefEdit control which collapses the form automatically?

Comment: Yes, the RefEdit control would collapse the form automatically but on the other hand it will return a string instead of a range, a validation of the input would be neccessary. In my suggestion one still needs to check if `cancel` was clicked.

Comment: I think the form resizing will work for me. @GSerg I tried the Me.Visible, but I seem to be getting a Compile error: "Function marked as restricted or uses a type not supported in Visual Basic"